# How do i build this JOIN statement? Having trouble with conditions

Tags: mysql, search, join

Now i JUST started getting into joins, so I'm probably missing some core understanding of it, but here's what I want to do:

I have a table with profiles, and several tables (roles, skills, titles etc) with a profile_id, some unrelated data and a value_id (one-to-one relationship)

The user will input an array of different value_ids, and i want to retrieve the id of all profiles that has a corresponding table with a value_id matching those we retrieve from the user.

Some values in the input are specified to only match against a certain table (roles and industries in this case), and that part is working right now. However what i couldn't do was to check if there's a match in **any** of the relevant tables.

---

**I have no idea how to style this block of sql. Sorry.** Edit: It styled itself. Neat.
In this example i have three values. One (88) is specified to search for a certain role, one is for an industry (128) and the third (73) must match at least one row in a set of tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(profiles.id) as id,  
FROM profiles  
INNER JOIN profile_experience_roles r ON(r.profile_id = profiles.id)  
INNER JOIN profile_experience_industries i ON(i.profile_id = profiles.id)  
INNER JOIN profile_experience_technology t ON(t.profile_id = profiles.id)  
INNER JOIN profile_wanted_roles w ON(w.profile_id = profiles.id)  
INNER JOIN profile_languages l ON(l.profile_id = profiles.id)   
WHERE r.value_id = 88 AND i.value_id = 128 AND  
(r.value_id = 73 OR i.value_id = 73 OR t.value_id = 73 OR w.value_id = 73 OR l.value_id = 73)
```

The final line is what's causing issues. Any help is appreciated.

Also, I've never posted here before, so I have no idea what im doing.
Thanks

Comment: That is and outstanding notation `Edit: It styled itself. Neat.`! You made my evening! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
WHERE r.value_id = 88 AND i.value_id = 128 AND 
73 IN (r.value_id, i.value_id, t.value_id, w.value_id, l.value_id)
```

In your case, you should be able to go with

```
WHERE r.value_id = 88 AND i.value_id = 128 AND 
73 IN (t.value_id, w.value_id, l.value_id)
```

Since `r.value_id` can never be 88 *and* 73. Same goes with `i.value_id` can't be 128 *and* 73.

Note that `INNER JOIN` demands a connection between *all* of these tables to fetch any rows.

Answer (score 1):

A good example on the difference in joins is here: [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-join)

The inner join might be the cause.  You might be joining on ids that don't exist and all of the data is not being returned.  I also included the change that Robin made about the IN and removing r.value and i.value

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(profiles.id) as id,  
FROM profiles  
RIGHT JOIN profile_experience_roles r ON(r.profile_id = profiles.id)  
RIGHT JOIN profile_experience_industries i ON(i.profile_id = profiles.id)  
RIGHT JOIN profile_experience_technology t ON(t.profile_id = profiles.id)  
RIGHT JOIN profile_wanted_roles w ON(w.profile_id = profiles.id)  
INNER JOIN profile_languages l ON(l.profile_id = profiles.id)   
WHERE profiles.id is not null AND r.value_id = 88 AND i.value_id = 128 AND 
    73 IN (t.value_id, w.value_id, l.value_id)
```